# gcc mingw compiler does not recognize CancelIOEx

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

I am trying to build some windows specific code that makes calls to CancelIOEx; however, the gcc linker keeps complaining that it can't find an implementation of CancelIOEx to link.

I tried specifying the kernel32 library file as a link library but that didn't work.

I am using the code blocks IDE.

Does anyone know how I can get around this problem?

Comment: What version of Windows SDK? According to MSDN, CancelIOEx requires Vista or newer.

Comment: I have the windows 7 SDK installed but I don't know if mingw/gcc is pointing to it.  How do I ascertain that?

Comment: The function is `CancelIoEx` - it is case sensitive (you used an uppercase O)

Answer (score 2):

Per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx) and [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Use_more_recent_defined_functions), you must define the version of windows you are using to be greater than Vista before including windows.h:

```
# define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_VISTA
# undef _WIN32_WINNT
# define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
```

This may also be better done on the gcc command line:

```
CPPFLAGS += -DNTDDI_VERSION=NTDDI_VISTA -D_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
```